# Arduino: struct order in unions

Tags: c++, gcc, arduino, arduino-ide

I have this code:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    unsigned long red:8;
    unsigned long green:8;
    unsigned long blue:8;
  };
  struct {
    unsigned long r:8;
    unsigned long g:8;
    unsigned long b:8;
  };
  unsigned long hex;
} UniColor;
```

My idea is to use hexadecimal codes as RGB colors automatically. For example:

```
UniColor color;
color.hex = 0xFF0000; // Red
Serial.println(color.red); // I hope that it prints 255.
Serial.println(color.green); // I hope that it prints 0.
Serial.println(color.blue); // I hope that it prints 0.
```

But when it prints:

```
0
0
255
```

I made a lot of test and I conclude that the struct order it's inverted. It's BGR insted RGB. I tried to change the order of the structures, but it does not work. The worst thing is that using the gcc compiler works correctly:

```
typedef union {
  struct {
    unsigned blue:8;
    unsigned green:8;
    unsigned red:8;
  };
  struct {
    unsigned b:8;
    unsigned g:8;
    unsigned r:8;
  };
  unsigned hex:24;
} UniColor;
...
UniColor color;
color.hex = 0xff0000;
cout << color.red << endl; // 255
cout << color.green << endl; // 0
cout << color.blue << endl; // 0
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Read up on "big endian" and "little endian" CPUs. That said, in C++ it is undefined behavior to write one member of a union and read through a different member. Don't do that. "Undefined behavior" means that (at best) even though things may seem to work today, they may fail tomorrow, or when you use a different compiler (or different version of a compiler)

Comment: Don't assign 0xFF0000.  Assign 0x112233 instead, and then look at the results.  I am surprised at your result though.

Comment: Instead of relying on arbitrary ordering of bytes in a `long`, considering implementing a `operator=(long)` for your `UniColor` object that assigns the `r`,`g` and `b` fields properly.

Comment: Even if type punning (using unions to switch types) was allowed, the order in which bit fields are filled is implementation defined. So you cannot rely on anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, as denoted in comments, type punning is undefined behaviour in C++. So you should only ever read the union member you last assigned a value to. Second problem is that the order in which bit fields are filled is implementation defined (some compilers might place the first member at MSB of the underlying type, most would prefer the LSB, though).

To get around any of these problems, I'd do the work you try to get simplified with bitfields manually:

```
class UniColor
{
    uint32_t color; // defined in cstdint header; safer than unsigned long or int!
public:
    UniColor(uint32_t color) : color(color) { }
    UniColor(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue)
        : color
        (
              static_cast<uint32_t>(red)   << 16
            | static_cast<uint32_t>(green) << 8
            | static_cast<uint32_t>(blue)
        )
        { }

    uint8_t red() // getter
    {
        return color >> 16;
    }
    void red(uint8_t value) // setter
    {
        color = color & 0x0000ffffU | static_cast<uint32_t>(red) << 16
    }
    uint8_t green()
    {
        return color >> 8 & 0xffU;
    }
    // rest analogously
};
```

You'll notice that I set up the 32 bits as `0xuurrggbb` (u: unused); if you prefer or need a different order, then adjust the bit shifts appropriately in above functions. You might even consider using the so far unused byte for the alpha channel...

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after researching I have not found a easy/universal way to reverse the bit fields. I have chosen to create a class to allocate the fields efficiently:

```
class RGBColor
{
    public:
        union{
          struct {
            unsigned blue:8;
            unsigned green:8;
            unsigned red:8;
          };
          struct {
            unsigned b:8;
            unsigned g:8;
            unsigned r:8;
          };
          unsigned long hex:24;
        };
        RGBColor(unsigned _r, unsigned _g, unsigned _b) : r(_r), g(_g), b(_b) {};
        RGBColor(unsigned _hex = 0x000000) : hex(_hex) {};
        void operator=(unsigned _hex)
        {
            hex = _hex;
        }
        void operator=(unsigned a[3])
        {
            r = a[0];
            g = a[1];
            b = a[2];
        }
};
```

It works. It is heavier than a simple structure without methods, but as we say in Spain: *there is no rose without thorns*.